# Keras Sequential model saved as tensorflow graph is missing train operation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I experimented with making simple models in keras and tensorflow and then saving them to pb files. When running the following command I noticed that the tensorflow example has a train operation but the keras example does not. **Question: Is there a way to find the train operation in a tensorflow graph that was created from a keras model or make sure that one is added?**

`tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()`

## Tensorflow Example

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1, 1], name='input')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1, 1], name='target')

y_ = tf.identity(tf.layers.dense(x, 1), name='output')

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_ - y), name='loss')
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, name='train')

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver_def = tf.train.Saver().as_saver_def()
tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
```

## Keras Example

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.GRU(20, input_shape=(10, 1), return_sequences=True, name='input'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
model.summary()

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver_def = tf.train.Saver().as_saver_def()
tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
```

## Edit

Thanks to Daniel Möller, after running fit training was added to the graph.
However, it is not named as nicely as a tensorflow model which seem to always use "train". I found the name "training/group_deps" for my keras model saved to a tensorflow graph.

It would be nice if the training name and target name could be found as easily as input and output, which can be found by:

```
model.input.name
model.output.name
```

But my problem seems to be solved, but need to dig through graph files each time. So it would be appreciated if someone knows a easier way. Goal, is to run networks using tensorflows C API.

## Edit 2

I found the summarize_graph tool in tesorflow. But the initial attempt to build it failed with bezel on windows. Currently other things are a priority so I didn't go further with this.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms#inspecting-graphs

Comment: Out of curiosity, try to call fit before saving.

Comment: Nice idea. It seems to have worked. Some more code ran and hit a different bug. Progress lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good thinking @Tensorflow Support.

I managed to find the correct sequence for saving a keras model. (At least it is working for me). My explanation is in the comments of the code block below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.GRU(20, input_shape=(10, 1), return_sequences=True, name='input'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
model.summary()

# Calling fit to get the training operations added to the graph
model.fit(input_data, target_data, validation_data=(input_vali, target_vali), batch_size=1, epochs=1)

# Important to call init after training so that training can also be reinitialized later
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
# Calling save after training like mentioned above
saver_def = tf.train.Saver().as_saver_def()

# Save graph as pb to be used later
tf.train.write_graph(tf.get_default_graph(),  "./", 'graph.pb', as_text=False)
# Save as text file as operation names not directly accessible by keras (to my knowledge) may be needed. Example target & training
tf.train.write_graph(tf.get_default_graph(),  "./", 'graph.txt', as_text=True)
```

I have been using the approach above with my own deep learning code to load the graph in TensorFlow C to run inferencing and training online in a code set to be deployed at some point in the future. (My confirmation in claiming the above approach works for my environment using tensorflow 1.15)

Answer (score 1):

Mentioning the solution (achieved so far) to the below problem for the benefit of the Community.

> Keras Sequential model saved as tensorflow graph is missing train
>   operation?

Running the Command, `model.fit` **before Saving the Model** using the Command,

`saver_def = tf.train.Saver().as_saver_def()`

includes the Training Operation in the Graph for a `Keras Sequential Model`.